# Intercepting push notifications coming from SNS

Tags: flutter, amazon-sns

We have a flutter app installed on ios and android. The apps all subscribe to a single SNS topic for push notifications (if granted the relevant permissions on first startup).

Is it possible for the app to intercept a push notification and decide based on various user settings whether or not to display it?

I am not talking about the user blocking all push notifications on the device.